# BEAM :ORACLE connector: NUMBER Data type : illegal argument type exception

Tags: java, apache-flink, apache-beam

```
String sql = "select CUSTOMER_ID, CITY, CUSTOMER_FIRSTTNAME from LIMA.CHECK_FLOW where CUSTOMER_ID < 1000";

        Schema schema = Schema.of(
        Schema.Field.of("CUSTOMER_ID", Schema.FieldType.INT32),
        Schema.Field.of("CITY", Schema.FieldType.STRING),
        Schema.Field.of("CUSTOMER_FIRSTTNAME", Schema.FieldType.STRING)
);

PCollection<Row> result = pipe.apply(JdbcIO.readRows()
    .withDataSourceConfiguration(configuration)
    .withQuery(sql)
    .withFetchSize(1000)
).setCoder(RowCoder.of(schema)).setRowSchema(schema);

PipelineResult nRes = pipe.run();
```

We are testing out Beams to see if it fits our usecases. Above is a simple, example. I get the following error

```
Caused by: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:39)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$ReadFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:232)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:191)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.metrics.DoFnRunnerWithMetricsUpdate.processElement(DoFnRunnerWithMetricsUpdate.java:62)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.translation.functions.FlinkDoFnFunction.flatMap(FlinkDoFnFunction.java:122)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.translation.functions.FlinkDoFnFunction.flatMap(FlinkDoFnFunction.java:59)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.chaining.ChainedFlatMapDriver.collect(ChainedFlatMapDriver.java:79)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.util.metrics.CountingCollector.collect(CountingCollector.java:35)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.DataSourceTask.invoke(DataSourceTask.java:208)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:779)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:566)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:127)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.LogicalTypes$FixedPrecisionNumeric.toInputType(LogicalTypes.java:268)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.LogicalTypes$FixedPrecisionNumeric.toInputType(LogicalTypes.java:246)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.SchemaUtil.lambda$createLogicalTypeExtractor$ca0ab2ec$1(SchemaUtil.java:279)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.SchemaUtil$BeamRowMapper.mapRow(SchemaUtil.java:344)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.SchemaUtil$BeamRowMapper.mapRow(SchemaUtil.java:322)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$ReadFn.processElement(JdbcIO.java:924)
```

Any help to resolve the error will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Tried, changing the data type of customer_id to integer, decimal etc. however, I get the same exception.

Comment: String sql = "select CUSTOMER_ID, CITY, CUSTOMER_FIRSTTNAME from LIMA.CHECK_FLOW where CUSTOMER_ID < 1000";   If I REMOVE CUSTOMER_ID from the SQL statement, then pipeline works properly

Comment: What is the actual type of CUSTOMER_ID in the database?

Comment: NUMBER ... Oracle

Comment: Wonder if this is the same issue as this. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-8897?jql=text%20~%20%22beam%20oracle%20number%22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue and is resolved as part of [this pull request](https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/15987).

The release will be out around January 2022. For now, you could apply the changes of this PR into your own project by creating theorg/apache/beam/sdk/io/jdbc/LogicalTypes.java class and copying the contents of this [file](https://github.com/vitaly-ivanov/beam/blob/9fa3bcaf724a9be53775af3d838154228022c9e2/sdks/java/io/jdbc/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/jdbc/LogicalTypes.java) in? I had the same advice.